# Self id not defined

Tags: python, python-2.7, class

I'm making the chaos game and I have a class for the SierpinskiTriangle. I am geting a NameError: name 'self' is not defined.

I've tried putting in the name of the class instead of self, and that doesn't work.

```
class SierpinskiTriangle(Fractal):

    v1 = Point(self.dimensions["MID_X"], self.dimensions["MIN_Y"])
    v2 = Point(self.dimensions["MIN_X"], self.dimensions["MAX_Y"])
    v3 = Point(self.dimensions["MAX_X"], self.dimensions["MAX_Y"])

    def __init__(self, dimensions):

        Fractal.__init__(self, dimensions)

        self.verticies = [v1, v2, v3]
        self.dimensions = dimensions
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):   File "C:\Users\HP.DESKTOP-29TB3JO\Desktop\Computer Science\CSC 132\Programs\The Chaos Game... Reloaded - Alayna Juneau\ChaosGameClass.py", line 11, in <module>
        from PointClassEct import *   File "C:\Users\HP.DESKTOP-29TB3JO\Desktop\Computer Science\CSC 132\Programs\The Chaos Game... Reloaded - Alayna Juneau\PointClassEct.py", line 94, in <module>
        class SierpinskiTriangle(Fractal):   File "C:\Users\HP.DESKTOP-29TB3JO\Desktop\Computer Science\CSC 132\Programs\The Chaos Game... Reloaded - Alayna Juneau\PointClassEct.py", line 96, in SierpinskiTriangle
        v1 = Point(self.dimensions["MID_X"], self.dimensions["MIN_Y"]) NameError: name 'self' is not defined
```

Comment: Please format the code and Traceback- select it and type `ctrl-k`. [Formatting posts](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) ... [Formatting help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) ... [Formatting Sandbox](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3122/formatting-sandbox)

Comment: You can't use `self` outside of a method. Also, everything you define on class level will be an attribute if the class and shared between all instances of the class.